# Error after composer update

Tags: symfony, composer-php, swiftmailer, symfony-2.7

I recently made a composer update on my Symfony app (2.7). Since I did this update, swiftmailer went from 2.4 to 2.5 and after the command, the console displayed me this error: 
[RuntimeException]

An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]

Unable to replace alias "swiftmailer.mailer.default.transport.real" with actual definition "mail".

[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]

You have requested a non-existent service "mail".
```

I tried to remove the swiftmailer directory in "vendor", but it didnt work.
Here's my composer.json:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
},
"scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.0"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.7-dev"
    }
}
```

}

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Finally made it to reinstall swiftmailer-bundle 2.4, but the problem is always there. HELP please !

Comment: This has definitely started happening since today. (Symfony 2.8 here.) -- Edit: Found out why, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has definitely been happening since today. (I'm on Symfony 2.8.17.) Reverting the Swiftmailer bundle back to version 2.4 fixed this for me.

In your **composer.json** file change

```
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
```

to

```
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.4",
```

Now do a composer update so you go back to version 2.4 of the Swiftmailer bundle and all should be well. Looks like there is a bug in the 2.5 update.

--

If you're still having problems try these commands to fully flush out cache:

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
rm app/bootstrap.php.cache
```

Also check your **composer.lock** file to ensure that the Swiftmailer bundle really has reverted back to 2.4. You should see a section like this:

```
    {
        "name": "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle",
        "version": "v2.4.2",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle.git",
            "reference": "ad751095576ce0c12a284e30e3fff80c91f27225"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/zipball/ad751095576ce0c12a284e30e3fff80c91f27225",
            "reference": "ad751095576ce0c12a284e30e3fff80c91f27225",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.3.2",
            "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": ">=4.2.0,~5.0",
            "symfony/config": "~2.7|~3.0",
            "symfony/dependency-injection": "~2.7|~3.0",
            "symfony/http-kernel": "~2.7|~3.0"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "symfony/console": "~2.7|~3.0",
            "symfony/framework-bundle": "~2.7|~3.0",
            "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7|~3.0",
            "symfony/yaml": "~2.7|~3.0"
        },
        "suggest": {
            "psr/log": "Allows logging"
        },
        "type": "symfony-bundle",
        "extra": {
            "branch-alias": {
                "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
            }
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Symfony\\Bundle\\SwiftmailerBundle\\": ""
            }
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "license": [
            "MIT"
        ],
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Symfony Community",
                "homepage": "http://symfony.com/contributors"
            },
            {
                "name": "Fabien Potencier",
                "email": "fabien@symfony.com"
            }
        ],
        "description": "Symfony SwiftmailerBundle",
        "homepage": "http://symfony.com",
        "time": "2016-12-20T04:44:33+00:00"
    },
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer.
I did what you said but it changed nothing. I already reinstalled the swiftmailer-bundle in 2.4.0 but it didn't fix the issue. I manually cleared the cache to be sure and the issue is still here.

Comment: Did you delete the "bootstrap.php.cache" file too?

Comment: I didn't, tried again and it worked. Last time I modified the swiftmailer-bundle version in composer.lock not composer.json, maybe it was the reason. Btw I love you man thx ! ^^

Comment: Ah yes, you must do it in the "json" file. This is what Composer reads to determine what it should install. The "lock" file just keeps a record of what Composer HAS installed, changing it manually will do nothing for you.

Comment: Yes this is nice for my global understanding of the framework and its plugins. I marked your answer as accepted since it contains a good explanation and you spotted the issue first try ^^ Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the issue you're describing was not caused by a bug, but by changed related dependency to `swiftmailer/swiftmailer`.

`You have requested a non-existent service "mail".` says that a service `mail` is missing, `Unable to replace alias "swiftmailer.mailer.default.transport.real" with actual definition "mail".` is a broad hint that this is related to swfitmailer transport `mail`, the class `Swift_Transport_MailTransport` using [insecure php `mail()` function](https://blog.ripstech.com/2017/why-mail-is-dangerous-in-php/). This transport is [deprecated since 
 swiftmailer version 5.4.5](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#transport) for security reasons.

In order to fix the issue, you need to

- switch from transport `mail` to a transport supported by current swiftmailer, or
- add `"swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "<6.0"` to your composer.json dependencies in order to prevent packages from installing swiftmailer v6.x where `Swift_Transport_MailTransport` is gone. Unfortunately, `symfony/swiftmailer-bundle` requires swiftmailer v6.x starting from v3.0.0, so you would need to require `"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2"`